# Python/Regex - Replace by pattern only at the end of string

Tags: python, regex

I need to replace every parenthesis at the end of a string. I use this code:

```
a = '1 (FR) Product (IT, DE, ES)'
b = re.sub(r' \((.*?)\)',r'', a)
```

But this will replace every parenthesis in my string. How do I tell python to replace it only if the pattern is at the end of the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture everything but `(` before `)` and end of string identifier `$`:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = '1 (FR) Product (IT, DE, ES)'
>>> re.sub(r'\(([^(]*\))$', '', a)
'1 (FR) Product '
```

Answer (score 0):

`if a[-1] == ")" a = a[:-2]`
will work